# How to add space between JButtons?

Tags: java, button, space

Ok so I have this panel and 2 buttons. I want to add space between the buttons. 
Here's my code:

```
    smallpan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    smallpan.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    panel2.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel2.add(smallpan);
    panel2.add(x);
    panel2.add(y);
```

Comment: What layout are you using?

Comment: Are you using AWT or Swing?

Comment: Im using BorderLayout

Comment: I imported awt and swing

Comment: You could change the layout manager...

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this - `BorderLayout.setHgap(int hgap)`for horizontal gap and `BorderLayout.setVgap()` for vertical gap between the elements. Or just specify it in the overloaded constructor - `BorderLayout(int horizontalGap, int verticalGap)`.

For more information see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#BorderLayout%28int,%20int%29)